# Firmware metthod to detect on board external RAM Size and its vendor

Tags: ram, bootloader, firmware

I am looking for a firmware solution, In the product I am working it is expected to work for at least 15 years, so there is a scope for external RAM extension in hardware, now as a firmware engineer I need to develop a boot loader firmware which can detect RAM size and its vendor then configure SOC accordingly, can any one help in finding best way to detect the RAM size and vendor through firmware, I am using SOC with ARM Cortex-A8 core. Here same boot loader should be able to run on any board with different RAM type. if it is not possible with firmware then is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

In generaly you cannot detect the size and vendor of a signle ram chip. You can determinate the ram size successively. Write some unique values to a specified address and read them back. As long as the values are equal, the ram chip can most likely handle this memory region.

In moderen memory modules there is an extra [SPD EEPROM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_presence_detect) wich provides the informations you looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I agree with you, in fact i have developed a similar algorithm to detect the size of a RAM however i need the vendor type as well so than i can do some configuration changes in SOC accordingly

Answer (score 0):

There might be various options based on your architecture. In case if your BIOS reads those information, you can fetch it from there. In certain cases, the  EEPROM shall be explicitly written with details of the components of board such as model, size, vendor details which in-turn can be fetched. Other options can be accessing SMBIOS and using logic similar to the one used by tools such as dmidecode. Also, based on your architecture, in some cases, hardware information are available in SPD that can be fetched.